# ES-Lint Rule or Plugin to identify the commented code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to find the rules or plugins of ES-Lint to identify the commented code so that I can remove that unnecessary code and clean my repository.

I would like to identify the multiline as well as single line code:

```
/* import CreateIncentive from './containers/create-incentive';
import AffiliateFilters from './containers/affiliate-filters'; */

//import NotificationsSettings from './containers/notifications-settings';
```

I have tried with below rules Bt it is not identifying the above kind of code :

```
"rules": {
        "no-warning-comments": [1, { "terms": ["todo", "fixme", "xxx"], "location": "anywhere" }],
        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", { "exceptions": ["-", "+"] }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the way to consider the code commented rule for Sonar. It is just a matter of ***Quality Profile***.I had set the DEFAULT profile to sonar-way but it has only 100 rules specified.

While the other profile available for JAVASCRIPT is ***Sonar way Recommended*** which has 148 rules and it also includes the rule to identify the code commented.

So switching the default profile to ***Sonar Way Recommended*** had the default rule to identify the commented code for multi-line or single line code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[`eslint-plugin-etc`](https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-etc/) Is a great suite of extra ESLint rules (often TS-related) and they offer one for commented out code:

https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-etc/blob/main/docs/rules/no-commented-out-code.md

Add it to your ESLint config

```js
rules: {
  "etc/no-commented-out-code": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plugin for that purpose:

### Install

```
npm install eslint-plugin-no-comments --save-dev
```

### Configuration

```
// eslintrc.js
{
    "plugins": ["eslint-plugin-no-comments"],
    "rules": {
        "eslint-plugin-no-comments/disallowComments": "error"
    }
}
```

[Full Documentation](https://github.com/wisniewski94/eslint-plugin-no-comments)

Comment: Looks like package was updated

`// eslintrc.js
{
    "plugins": ["no-comments"],
    "rules": {
        "no-comments/disallowComments": "error"
    }
}`

worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try `no-inline-comments` ESLint rule

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inline-comments

Comment: It will only give me the warning in case of disallowing comments on the same line as code.